# Google Maps API Geocoder getting correct long and lat but placing wrong marker

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Below is my code to take the address I want and place it on a map using Google Maps API. Everytime I run the page it places the marker and centers the map over the ocean south of Ghana even tho if I console log the long and lat that it gets from the address it is the correct coordinates for Belfast, Northern Ireland.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {

    var latNo = null;
    var lngNo = null;

    var postcode = $(".postcode-var").text();
    var address = "Belfast, Northern Ireland";

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latNo = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lngNo = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(latNo + "" + lngNo);
        } else {
            console.log("Cannot find address");
        }

    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latNo, lngNo),
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#6863CE"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
    };

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latNo, lngNo),
        map: map
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try not redeclaring the var where you assign latNo and lngNo

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latNo = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lngNo = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(latNo + "" + lngNo);
    } else {
        console.log("Cannot find address");
    }

});
```

redeclaring the var for the latNo and lngNdo you shadowing the content  in the if content

Or try assigning the coord to an existing marker

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {

    var latNo = null;
    var lngNo = null;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latNo, lngNo),
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#6863CE"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
    };

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: null
    });

    var postcode = $(".postcode-var").text();
    var address = "Belfast, Northern Ireland";

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var myLatLng = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latNo = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lngNo = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(latNo + "" + lngNo);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker.setMap(map);

        } else {
            console.log("Cannot find address");
        }

    });
```